# Como fazer um "JOIN" em duas collections no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Eu sei que o MongoDB não tem inner join,
mas preciso mesmo filtrar os dados de uma *collection* tomando por referência o seu `_id` em outra *collection*.

Preciso exibir apenas os projetos de um determinado usuário.

Fora de questão reestruturar a base.

Collections:

```
usuarios: { _id: ObjectId("..."), nome: "usuario", ... }
```

projetos:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("..."), nome: "projeto1", ...}
```

usuariosProjetos:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("..."), idProjeto, idUsuario }
```

---

Em suma, quero passar o `_id` do usuário e ele me trazer todos os projetos dele sem mudar a estrutura acima. É possível?

Comment: Você quer fazer isso dentro da Shell do Mongo?

Comment: Tanto faz. Gostaria de saber se existe uma saída.

Comment: Existe, mas envolve uma linguagem de programação. O MongoDB, conforme a resposta dada, não tem suporte nativo a `joins`. Você que tem que fazer sua aplicação ler os dados dependentes.

Comment: Você tem o código de alguma solução com php pra eu entender?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/modeling-data-relationships-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O MongoDB não suporta `joins`.

Infelizmente sua estrutura não condiz com o funcionamento do MongoDB.

O Mongodb é um banco de dados não relacional, você deve centralizar os dados de cada consulta num mesmo documento.

Os dados da collection `usuariosProjetos` deveriam fazer parte da collection `usuarios`.

Comment: Bom, não existe o conceito de "tabela" no MongoDB porque é um banco de dados sem *schema*. O *schema* é definido na aplicação.

Comment: Sim, eu troquei os termos, queria dizer collection

Comment: Agora sim está ok. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Acrescentando que a partir da sua versão 3.4, o mongodb traz o operador $lookup, que permite unir registros de duas coleções, a partir de algum valor em comum entre as duas. Mas é apenas isso. Joins complexas como em banco relacionais, esqueça.

Answer (score 1):

Nas versões mais recentes o mongoDb suporta o operador $lookup em agregações.

O código ficaria assim:

Produto

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const produtoSchema = Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  quantidade: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  preco: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  precoCusto: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = ProdutoModel = mongoose.model("produtos", produtoSchema);
```

Compra

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const compraSchema = Schema({
  id_produto: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  data: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  quantidade: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  preco: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  }
});

module.exports = CompraModel = mongoose.model("compras", compraSchema);
```

consulta

```
const CompraModel = require("../models/CompraModel");

const compraProdutoJoin = [
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'produtos', 
      'localField': 'id_produto', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'produto'
    }
  }
];

module.exports = class CompraService {
  static async getAllCompras() {
    try {

      const allCompras = await CompraModel.aggregate(compraProdutoJoin);
      
      return allCompras;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Erro ao recuperar Compras ${error}`);
      throw new Error(`Erro ao recuperar Compras ${error}`);
    }
  }
};
```

Se quiser melhorar o lookup para ficar um inner join em caso de relacionamento n para 1 pode fazer assim

```
const compraProdutoInnerJoin = [
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'produtos', 
      'localField': 'id_produto', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'produto'
    }
  }, { // para fazer com que fique um campo e não uma lista
    '$addFields': {
        'produto': {
            '$arrayElemAt': [
                '$produto', 0
            ]
        }
    }
}, { // para virar inner join e não left join
  '$match': {
      'produto': {
          '$exists': true
      }
  }
}
];
```